# Angular Component doesn't see an interface that is in the same file

Tags: angular, interface, components

It's the full file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../core/api.service';

// import { MatTableDataSource, Matsort } from '@angular/material';

export interface PersonalList {
  Name: string;
  Position: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-list',
  templateUrl: './personal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-list.component.css']
})
export class PersonalListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Name', 'Position'];
  personal = PersonalList[];
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getPersonalList().subscribe((data: PersonalList[]) => {
      var i = 0;

      console.log();
    })
  }

}
```

Without using the interface it works, but I can't use the fetched data in the table.

What have I missed?

Comment: What does "doesn't see" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
personal: PersonalList[];
```

instead of

```
personal = PersonalList[];
```

Comment: Oh, Thank You! I didn't think that I could make a mistake here.